# Script arrays deleted after reading from csv

Tags: javascript

try in to read the CSV file using file reader in Javascript, I update the script declared arrays. But as soon as the reading is done, all the data from the arrays is deleted. I am not sure why is this happening, pretty new to js. I believe it's because of the scope of the arrays but I declared them as global but still, it isn't working.

```
var paper = [];
var recyclables = [];
var compost = [];
var landfill = [];

function readCsvFileData(type, index) {
    readCsv();
    if(type == "paper"){
        console.log("requested type - " + paper.length);
        console.log("wrong answer here -- 0 ");
        return paper[index];
    }
}


function readCsv() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            console.log(this.responseText);
            var line = this.responseText.split("\n");
            for(let row = 1; row < line.length; row++){
                let rowData = line[row].split(',');
                for(let col = 1; col < rowData.length; col++){
                    if(col == 1 && paper.length<12){
                        paper.push(rowData[col]);
                    }
                    if(col == 2 && recyclables.length<12){
                        recyclables.push(rowData[col]);
                    }
                    if(col == 3 && compost.length<12){
                        compost.push(rowData[col]);
                    }
                    if(col == 4 && landfill.length<12){
                        landfill.push(rowData[col]);
                    }
                    if(paper.length==12 && recyclables.length==12 && compost.length==12 && landfill.length==12){
                        console.log("retruning "+landfill.length);
                        console.log("correct answer here -- 12");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    xhttp.open('GET', "Data.csv", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to verify that the data is actually getting populated in the arrays in the first place?

Comment: i thinks is beceause you use the arrays in anonym functions, so the values are local

Comment: The `readCsv()` function returns before the reply is received from the server because of the `async` parameter is set to `true` in the `open()` call.

Comment: @sam the arrays get populated without any problem, but it somehow gets deleted after the function returns.

Comment: @JayBuckman thanks a lot, didn't notice that. I set it to false and it worked. Can you please explain to me why it happened even though I ran it on the debugger and it ran the readCsv function first and populated all the arrays.

Comment: @AryanArora - using the debugger probably allowed the async call to complete as you were stepping through the code making it look like the code was working as intended.  Please read Sam's excellent answer - as he indicated, you should avoid synchronous calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jay Buckman mentioned in the comments, you're doing this asynchronously which means the function `readCsv` returns immediately, rather than waiting for the `send()` method to complete. At that point your `readCsvFileData` function continues on to the `if` condition you have there, which is working off arrays that haven't yet been populated. You need to add an event listener/ callback method. Give this a shot:

```
var paper = [];
var recyclables = [];
var compost = [];
var landfill = [];

function readCsvFileData(type, index) {
    readCsv(function() {
        if(type == "paper"){
            console.log("requested type - " + paper.length);
            console.log("wrong answer here -- 0 ");
            return paper[index];
        }
    });
}


function readCsv(onCompleteCallback) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            // ... your normal implementation

            // invoke your complete callback, which will run the function
            // you passed through to this function
            onCompleteCallback();
        }
    }

    xhttp.open('GET', "Data.csv", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

[Here's some further reading on the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open). In general, setting the async argument is preferred. Without it, your call occurs synchronously which could lock the main thread (i.e. the users browser) until it completes, which isn't ideal.